# I want to move the rectangle with mouse drag over the image, What's wrong with the code

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, mouse

Any help with the code below...

I want to move the rectangle with mouse drag over the image, What's wrong with the code.
Do I need to paint the image or the Jlabel is causing the problem.

```
 public class imagecrop  extends JFrame  {
          int  x,y,width=90, height=96 ;

     public imagecrop(BufferedImage image) {
           super("Crop");           
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setSize(546, 452);
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel(corner(image));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 530, 382);
        getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("OK");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(220, 393, 89, 21);
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private ImageIcon corner(BufferedImage image) {

        javaxt.io.Image image1 = new javaxt.io.Image(image);
        image1.setHeight(382);
        image=image1.getBufferedImage();
        ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(image);

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                repaint();
                x=e.getX();
                y=e.getY();
        }});
        Graphics2D graph = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        graph.draw((Shape) new Rectangle( x, y, width, height));
        System.out.println(x+y);
        return image2;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: and the rectangle is not moving?

Comment: yes not moving at all

Answer (score 2):

You in fact just create image once and store it in the `JLabel`. After that coordinates are changed but the image is not recreated.

I would suggest ot override `paintComponent()` method of the `JLabel` and call `g.draw((Shape) new Rectangle( x, y, width, height));` in the method to reflect changes.

Comment: can u please elaborate